# Steps in CSS for longer words

Tags: html, css, animation

I found this great example: http://codepen.io/tacrossman/pen/GJglH

```
<div class="animation">
  <span class="type">beaches<span>_</span></span>
    <span class="type">color<span>_</span></span>
    <span class="type">happiness and blah blah<span>_</span></span>
    <span class="type">wonder<span>_</span></span>
    <span class="type">sugar<span>_</span></span>
    <span class="type">sunshine<span>_</span></span>
</div>
```

The problem is for the third span, I added 'and blah blah' to the end of the line. As you can see, the text now bunches up and doesn't follow the same transition effect as the others. I've tried adjusting the values but then the other four spans are screwed up. Any ideas?

Comment: "doesn't work properly" is not a proper problem description.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure the text doesn't wrap using this additional CSS:

```
.type{
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

or

```
.type{
  white-space: pre;
}
```

[Updated CodePen](http://codepen.io/BrianDillingham/pen/taykw) - Better than editing the text (in my opinion):

Comment: +1 This is the better solution, you don't want to have to add `&nbsp;` every 5 characters :)

Comment: Thanks for the CodePen, Brian!

Comment: Thanks Brian and GolezTrol! This is a great solution too.

Answer (score 4):

Adding non-breaking spaces between the words fixes the issue:

```
<div class="animation">
  <span class="type">beaches<span>_</span></span>
    <span class="type">color<span>_</span></span>
    <span class="type">happiness&nbsp;and&nbsp;blah&nbsp;blah<span>_</span></span>
    <span class="type">wonder<span>_</span></span>
    <span class="type">sugar<span>_</span></span>
    <span class="type">sunshine<span>_</span></span>
</div>
```

New version here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Jtlnk

Comment: Ahh perfect, thank you Holf! (I'll be able to accept in 7 min).

Answer (score 0):

use

```
<span class="type">happiness&nbsp;and&nbsp;blah&nbsp;blah<span>_</span></span>
```